# Что написать в htaccess чтобы при запросе site1/folder/.. отображались файлы из site2/folder/...?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

Имеется рабочий сайт на Joomla, к примеру на поддомене shop.site.ru
Для модификаций и тестирования мы его скопировали на новый поддомен test.site.ru, однако папку images не стали копировать из-за большого её объема (тысячи фотографий от компонента Интернет-магазина).

Таким образом на test.site.ru нет фотографий, а хотелось бы их там иметь.

Что написать в .htaccess чтобы все обращения к файлам и подкаталогам в папке test.site.ru/images были переадресованы на shop.site.ru/images, т.е. по сути сделать так чтобы на нашем тестовом сайте test.site.ru отображались файлы из папки поддомена shop.site.ru ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RedirectMatch "^/images/(.*)" "http://shop.site.ru/images/$1"
```

Comment: неа, не работает к сожалению (

Comment: mod_alias подключен? Если нет, то попробую сейчас для mod_rewrite написать.

Comment: помогло решение вида:
RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://shop.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: Да, с адресом сайта я перестарался, поправил в ответе.